# SSAS rename objects

Tags: ssas, data-warehouse, olap

Is there an efficient way to rename objects in SSAS?

My customer dimension has the following attributes:

- Customer Key
- Customer Name

Is there a way to rename "Customer name" without breaking the MDX queries or client queries in Excel?

Is it good practice to use user friendly names or is it better to use technical names (e.g. cust_name) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expect humans to use the cube then fields should be named in a human friendly way. The best cubes speak in business terminology.

If you can't afford to break existing reports then you can consider using an English translation to change the visible field name while ensuring the existing reports and MDX calcs and queries don't break.

http://www.ssas-info.com/VidasMatelisBlog/37_customizing-object-names-in-analysis-services-database-using-translations